# How do I escape a forward slash in a filename in rsync?

Tags: rsync

I am running a command like:

```
rsync -vuan "/Volumes/Working/foldername/" "/Volumes/Archive/foldername/"
```

It doesn't work when folder names have a '/' like "12/13 The Street"

How do I escape the forwardslash?

Answer (score 5):

It is really simple: unix doesn't allow / but Mac fakes it. The GUI uses a slash but the unix uses a colon :

Just open up the terminal and ls the directory and it'll show you colons instead of slashes.  Classic mac forbid colons in names because that was the path delimiter; Applescript still works this way and probably Carbon APIs as well. The modern Finder forbids the user from using : but it does the translation of slashes to colons.

Answer (score 0):

Linux does not support to have / in the filenames. By default if u need to escape a particular string we use

\Character_to_be_escaped

Even windows does not allow the use of / in the filename. To my knowledge, having a file or folder with name / is not possible.

You can check
i tried to create a folder

```
mkdir 1/2
mkdir: cannot create directory `1/2': No such file or directory
```

Creating folder by escaping

```
mkdir 1\/2
mkdir: cannot create directory `1/2': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I'm on Mac and there are already folders with a '/' in them, but using  a backslash in the rsync command doesn't work.   I have renamed the folders to move them, but I just wondered if there was a proper way to do it.

Comment: I thought your on Linux Box! Sorry